# get values to edit in an other page with Angular

Tags: angularjs

I have values that I want to edit in an other page

```
<tr ng-repeat="facilitator in listFacilitators"  ng-click="showDetails(facilitator);goToFacilitatorP()"> 
    <td>{{facilitator.username}}</td> 
    <td><li><ul>{{facilitator.cwsessionsAnime}}</ul></li></td>
    <td><li><ul>{{facilitator.profilFollow}}</ul></li></td> 
</tr>
```

when I click on  I'm supposing to be redirected in another page to show the details and edit them , so I tried to do this in the controller:

```
$scope.showDetails= function(facilitator){
    $scope.selectedFac= facilitator;
}
```

and in the second page, I do this:

```
<tr>
    <td> {{selectedFac.username}}</td>
    <td> {{selectedFac.lastname}}</td>
    <td> {{selectedFac.firstname}}</td>
    <td> {{selectedFac.title}}</td>
</tr>
```

it works in the same page but not when I'm redirected, can you help me please?

```
UPDATE:
```

I do this but I still haven't data in the seconde page: 
1- In the first controller for the 1 page I declared:

```
profilCtrl.controller('ProfilCtrl', [ '$scope','$location', 'profilService', 'facilitatorPService', function($scope,$location, profilService, facilitatorPService) {
/* ---- appel a facilitator Service ---- */
var facilitator = '';// What ever this is set to in the first place
facilitatorPService.facilitator = facilitator;
```

2- In my 2nd controller (for the second in where I want to show the details) , I have declared:

```
facilitatorPCtrl.controller('facilitatorPCtrl', [ '$scope','$rootScope','$cookieStore','$location','membreService','facilitatorPService','userService',function($scope,$rootScope,$cookieStore,$location, membreService,facilitatorPService, userService) {
facilitatorPservice.editFacil= function($scope){
    $scope.showDetails = function(){
        $scope.selectedFac = facilitatorPService.facilitator;
    }
};
```

3- Ans in my service facilitatorPService I have this:

```
facilitatorPService.factory('facilitatorPService', [ '$resource','$http', function($resource,$http) {
    var service = {                 
            getAllFacilitators : function($scope){  
                return $resource('/gari-web/services/facilitators/AllFacilitators', {}, {
                    query : {
                        method : 'GET', isArray:true,
                         }}
                });
            }, 
            editFacil: function($scope){
                var self= this;
                self.facilitator={};
            }};
    return service;
} ]);
```

4- in My html page I put this:

```
<td>{{selectedFac.username}}</td>
```

Can someone please tell me what I did wrong, I don't find the mistake

Answer (score 1):

Controllers are 'flushed' when you change views. To keep data from a view to another, store your data within a **Service**.

**UPDATE**

```
 .service('FacilitatorService', [
        function() {
            var self = this;
            self.facilitator = {};
        }
    ])
```

Then in your controllers, inject yourself the service you just created.

```
 .controller('FirstController', ['FacilitatorService',
        function(FacilitatorService) {
            var facilitator = '';// What ever this is set to in the first place
            FacilitatorService.facilitator = facilitator;
        }
    ])
```

And in your second controller

```
 .controller('SecondController', ['FacilitatorService', '$scope',
        function(FacilitatorService, $scope) {
            $scope.showDetails = function(){
                $scope.selectedFac = FacilitatorService.facilitator;
            }
        }
    ])
```

Like this, your `FacilitatorService.facilitator` data will be accesible in all your controllers that use `FacilitatorService`

Comment: thank you for replying, but can you give me an example please of how could I do this?

Comment: thank you for replying, I update my files like you said (I put the update in the top) , but I still haven't data in the seconde page , can you tike a look please

Comment: Can you make a plunkr or fiddle with your actual code, it will be simpler

Comment: I put it in plunkr, but I think I miss some thing because the data is not displayed in the first page: https://plnkr.co/edit/VxZfLghO1Fsx5J8TlMeI?p=preview

Comment: you made a factory, it is supposed to be a `.service`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using ui router, this resolve two problems, the view change and the data share.

**Read more about router ui**

doc http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router

The current state

```
$stateProvider
  .state('current', {
    url: "/curent",
    templateUrl: 'current.html',
    controller: 'currentCtrl'
  })
```

Then you can choose how change the view and share the data, the first is  the controller, the second is html. Only use one

From current controller (option 1)

```
$scope.showDetails= function(facilitator){
    $state.go('togo', {myCurrentdata: facilitator}) ;
}
```

From current html (option2)

```
<tr ng-repeat="facilitator in listFacilitators" ui-sref="togo({myCurrentdata : facilitator})"> 
    <td>{{facilitator.username}}</td> 
    <td><li><ul>{{facilitator.cwsessionsAnime}}</ul></li></td>
    <td><li><ul>{{facilitator.profilFollow}}</ul></li></td> 
</tr>
```

The state that you want to go

```
$stateProvider
  .state('togo', {
    url: "/togo",
    templateUrl: 'togo.html',
    controller: 'togoCtrl'
    param: {myCurrentdata: null}
  })
```

To go controller

```
if($stateParams.myCurrentdata){
   $scope.selectedFac = $stateParams.myCurrentdata
}
```